# Do different formats of the same book need to be registered separately?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, legal, copyright

We're self-publishing a book in both paperback and e-book format. The content between the versions will be identical except for some formatting corrections (mainly white-space) made for the digital version.

We know that we need to have separate ISBN's for each version, but we are a little confused whether or not both versions need to be registered with the Copyright Office.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: No. You are supposed to register only the "best edition" with the copyright office. They have a long list of criteria for what constitutes the best edition, but it's things like a hard cover takes precedence over a paperback. See http://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ07b.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Copyright applies the moment given work is solidified on a medium - the registration is not necessary at all providing that you have any reliable proof that you are the author. (you *do* have the copyright but the court is not omniscent, you need *some* way to show that you do.)

Registering with the Copyright Office only serves as such a proof, and a very solid one. Once it exists, there is no way for the other version with such minor differences to be someone else's work and not infringe on yours. It's a clear derivative, so a single registration is enough of a proof in any copyright cases - you have the claim to the original, so all derivative works either belong to you or infringe upon your rights, whichever is the case you win.